# Windows Update KB2919355 fails to install. Update Error 80004004

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-update

I've been having issues with my laptop that some people mentioned could be fixed with the new update. I have updates set to install automatically, but sure enough when I looked at the update history under KB2919355 it said 'failed to install'. The error code it gave me is 80004004.

Also, when trying to dowload the update from the website, it says it is not applicable to my system

Comment: Was Win 8 or 8.1 what came with your system or did you previously upgrade from a prior version of Windows?

Comment: Install all updates except *KB2919355* then install *KB2919355*.  The requirements to install *KB2919355* are [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42327)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, there are some dependencies, requiring a certain installation sequence.  From [Microsoft's web site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42327), try this installation procedure:

1. To start the download, click the Download button and then do one of the following, or select another language from Change Language and then click Change.

   - Click Run to start the installation immediately.
   - Click Save to copy the download to your computer for installation at a later time.
2. These KB's must be installed in the following order: clearcompressionflag.exe, KB2919355, KB2932046, KB2959977, KB2937592, KB2938439, and KB2934018.  [Note: this is actually a cumulative collection of updates and those are the components.]
3. KB2919442 is a prerequisite for Windows 8.1 Update and should be installed before attempting to install KB2919355.  [Check the installed updates list to verify that it was previously installed.]

If you still have problems, try the procedure after a clean boot (see [How to perform a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929135)).

Comment: Kept having problems, but just running Windows update itself instead of manual installation somehow fixed it..